I cannot connect to the sharepoint API and I have no idea why
I am trying to connect to SharePoint via my node.js application. I have the most basic of scripts at the moment as I am trying to simply create a connection to my SharePoint site.
the steps I took to do this:

create a SharePoint site
create/register an app via azure
get the client ID and tenant ID
create a secret key via certificates and secrets
go into API permissions > add new permission > sharepoint > application permission > Sites.fullcontrol (something like so)
6)go to node.js create config.js file & app.js

config.js:
module.exports = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'xxxx',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx',
        clientSecret: 'xxx'
    },
    sharepoint: {
        siteUrl: 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx',
        scopes: ['https://xxx.sharepoint.com/.default']
    }
};

now my app.js is the following:
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const axios = require('axios');
const config = require('./config');

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
    auth: config.auth
});

async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        const result = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
            scopes: config.sharepoint.scopes
        });
        return result.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error acquiring token:', error);
    }
}

async function connectToSharePoint() {
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
    console.log(accessToken);
    if (!accessToken) {
        console.error('Failed to acquire access token');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Access Token acquired successfully');
    const siteUrl = `${config.sharepoint.siteUrl}/_api/web`;

    console.log('Attempting to connect to:', siteUrl);

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            }
        });
        console.log('Successfully connected to SharePoint!');
        console.log('Site Title:', response.data.d.Title);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to SharePoint:', error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
        }
    }
}

connectToSharePoint();

I was expecting a connection if successful, but I keep getting this error instead:
sp1 % node app.js
Access Token acquired successfully
Attempting to connect to: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web
Error connecting to SharePoint: Request failed with status code 401
Response status: 401
Response data: "Unsupported app only token."

In app-only scenarios, SharePoint only accepts access tokens requested with a client certificate , not a client secret. Instead of client secret, create one client certificate and upload it to Azure AD app registration and modify your code accordingly to resolve the error. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#can-i-use-other-means-besides-certificates-for-realizing-app-only-access-for-my-azure-ad-app

This worked thank you so much. I have a follow up question for you @Sridevi. Is the way you recommended doing it with the certificate the only way because I set the API permissions to the application itself as opposed to delegated permissions for sharepoint. When would it be best to choose one or the other? Again thank you so much!

If you want to use permissions of Application type, the only way is to make use of client certificate authentication. If you want to use Delegated permissions, you need to modify your entire code and switch to delegated flows like authorization code that involves user to sign in at least once.

Using app permissions with a client certificate is best when your app works on its own without needing a specific user. Delegated permissions are for situations where the app acts on behalf of users who are logged in.

The error usually occurs if you use client secret while acquiring token to access SharePoint API in app-only scenarios.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code in my environment to access SharePoint with token acquired with client secret:

To resolve the error, make use of client certificate authentication by creating one certificate and upload to Azure AD application like this:

In my case, I used below modified code by adding client certificate related parameters and got response successfully as below:
config.js:
module.exports = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'appId',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id',
        clientCertificate: {
            thumbprint: 'cert_thumbprint',
            privateKey: {
                keyFilename: 'C:/certpath/name.pem',
                passphrase: 'password'
            }
        }
    },
    sharepoint: {
        siteUrl: 'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sritestsite',
        scopes: ['https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default']
    }
};

app.js
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config');

let cca;

async function initializeMsal() {
    const clientCertificate = {
        thumbprint: config.auth.clientCertificate.thumbprint,
        privateKey: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(config.auth.clientCertificate.privateKey.keyFilename, 'utf8'),
            passphrase: config.auth.clientCertificate.privateKey.passphrase
        }
    };

    cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
        auth: {
            clientId: config.auth.clientId,
            authority: config.auth.authority,
            clientCertificate
        }
    });
}

async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        if (!cca) {
            await initializeMsal();
        }
        const result = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
            scopes: config.sharepoint.scopes
        });
        return result.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error acquiring token:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

async function connectToSharePoint() {
    try {
        const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
        if (!accessToken) {
            console.error('Failed to acquire access token');
            return;
        }

        const siteUrl = `${config.sharepoint.siteUrl}/_api/web`;
        const response = await axios.get(siteUrl, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
            }
        });

        console.log('Successfully connected to SharePoint!');
        console.log('Site Title:', response.data.d.Title);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to SharePoint:', error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error('Response status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('Response data:', JSON.stringify(error.response.data, null, 2));
        }
    }
}

initializeMsal().then(() => {
    connectToSharePoint();
});

Response:

If you want to use permissions of Application type, the only way is to make use of client certificate authentication. For Delegated type permissions, you need to modify your entire code and switch to delegated flows like authorization code that involves user to sign in at least once.
Using app permissions with a client certificate is best when your app works on its own without needing a specific user. Delegated permissions are for situations where the app acts on behalf of users who are logged in.
