Access Sharepoint Online Files from .NET Worker Service via Microsoft Graph/OAuth - Unauthorized or Access Denied error (401)
I want to create a .NET Worker Service (c#) to access files hosted on Sharepoint online.
I have registered an application for this in the Azure portal as follows:

Register an application (Single tenant)
API permissions -> Add a permission -> SharePoint -> Application permissions -> Sites.FullControl.All
Grant admin consent confirmation.
Certificates & secrets -> Add a client secret

The code looks like this:
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

string siteUrl = "https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointwebsite/";
string clientId = "XXX";
string tenantId = "XXX";
string clientSecret = "XXX";

var confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

var authResult = await confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://myname.sharepoint.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken;
    };

    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + web.Title);
}

I get an access token, but access to the SharePoint site is denied (401).
Which step (permissions) may I have forgotten?
Thank you very much for your help.

The error usually occurs if you use client secret while acquiring token to access SharePoint API in app-only scenarios. Switch to client certificate authentication and check if it works. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78681359/i-cannot-connect-to-the-sharepoint-api-and-i-have-no-idea-why/78681885#78681885

I think @Sridevi is right. Most probably Unauthorized error is because you're using client secret, otherwise you seem to have given permissions and granted consent as per your description. Also make sure to check your scope value after changing to certificate. The other similar question, is in context of a node.js application, so code is a little different. I've provided you a C# version to do the same thing along with some guidance links.

When you use an Azure AD registered application to authenticate with SharePoint online, you'll need to use a certificate to prove the application’s identity while requesting an access token. In a normal scenario you could use either a secret or a certificate, but AFAIK SharePoint online blocks anything other than certificate. Microsoft documentation for the whole scenario is available here -

Granting access via Azure AD App-Only
FAQ > Options other than certificate are blocked by SharePoint online



Step 1 - Associate certificate credential with your registered application
a. If you have a certificate already you don't need to do this part and simply upload the certificate, otherwise you can create a self-signed certificate using the following PowerShell script. (NOTE: self-signed cert may not be good for production scenarios, but can help you verify the concept in dev)
$certname = "MyTestCertificate"    
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:\WorkFolder\$certname.cer"  
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "MyStrongPassword123#" -Force -AsPlainText  
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:\WorkFolder\$certname.pfx" -Password $mypwd   

b In the App registrations tab for the client application:


Select Certificates & secrets > Certificates.
Click on Upload certificate and select the certificate file to upload.
Once the certificate is uploaded, the thumbprint, start date, and
expiration values are displayed.

Step 2 - Use certificate instead of client secret to acquire token
I've just taken your C# code and modified it to use a certificate.
Important part:
var confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\WorkFolder\MyTestCertificate.pfx", "MyStrongPassword123#")).Build();

var authResult = await confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://myname.sharepoint.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

Complete code:
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

string siteUrl = "https://myname.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointwebsite/";
string clientId = "XXX";
string tenantId = "XXX";

var confidentialClientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithCertificate(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\WorkFolder\MyTestCertificate.pfx", "MyStrongPassword123#")).Build();

var authResult = await confidentialClientApp.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://myname.sharepoint.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    context.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken;
    };

    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + web.Title);
    Console.ReadLine();
}


Perfect. Using a certificate instead of the client secret was the solution. Thank you very much!

This very helpful.
